# How to update group membership remotely

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I'd like to see if there is a way to update a users machines group membership without having to restart the computer, and without having their login information. Ideally looking for something I can execute remotely with a script. I've found different ways to refresh the group membership, but most need the login information of the user, or direct access to the machine. We're trying to find a way that allows as little disruption to the user as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart is not necessary, but a logoff-logon cycle is needed to refresh NTLM authentication. While it's possible e.g. to force logoff after 5 minutes using `shutdown /l /f /t 300`, the `/l` for logoff is not available remotely with `/m \\target`.

Additionally, Kerberos authentication tickets can be reset with [`klist.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/klist) since Windows 7. As you were looking for a solution that resets all Kerberos tickets, you need to use the special identifier:

```
klist -lh 0 -li 0x3e7 purge
```

There is a script for [Purging the Kerberos ticket cache via klist on a remote machine](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Purging-the-Kerberos-7ab3c0ce). You could either use it as is or adopt the methods described:

> The script uses `Win32_ScheduledJob` to schedule Klist. Klist queries
>   the current tickets (`klist -lh 0 -li 0x3e7 tickets`) and purges them
>   (`klist -lh 0 -li 0x3e7 purge`). `Win32_Process` is then used to create
>   the process `echo N | gpupdate /force /target:computer`.

Comment: I meant logoff-logon cycle, my bad. Also this seems to work but we do use backgrounds as part of our group memberships, and those still don't get reset unless you logoff-logon. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Not that I know of. Kerberos authentication tickets can be purged, and Kerberos is the replacement for NTLM and default since Windows 2000. See [Comparing Windows Kerberos and NTLM Authentication Protocols](http://www.itprotoday.com/security/comparing-windows-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-protocols).